./run-db.sh returned ./run-db.sh: line 2: /usr/libexec/java_home: No such file or directory
I am trying to setup a derby connection (db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin)

gitbash to the folder path
run ./run-db.sh
result returned: ./run-db.sh: line 2: /usr/libexec/java_home: No such file or directory

I'm using jdk21
Please help, I'm running out of solutions TT_TT
I tried changing the JAVA_HOME, DERBY_HOME paths manually
I tried deleting, re-downloaded and extracted the folder to C://Program Files
I tried countless provided solutions but none is working for me.

/usr/libexec/java_home is a macOs command, and you are in Windows. If there is a batch file, use it instead.

there is a batch file to start the server(startNetworkServer.bat), but it returned nothing
